# Add flat array to v-model by multiple checkboxes in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, vue.js, vuejs2

in my Vue component I have checkboxes with array of items set to checkbox value:

```
<div v-for="group in groups">

   <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="group">       

   <template v-for="item in group">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="item" v-model="selected">
   </template>
</div>
```

My object groups is array of arrays looks like this:

```
let groups = [
  [
    {id:1, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
    {id:2, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}
  ], 
  [
    {id:5, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}, 
    {id:8, foo1: '...', foo2: '...'}
  ],
];
```

So in template `item` is represented by array. My goals is when I check checkbox, to model `selected` will append flat array so for example when I check both checkboxes generated in loop, I will got in my `selected` 4 objects instead of 2 arrays of objects. (selected will `[{id: 1, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 5, ...}, {id: 8, ...}]` )

It also should works when some checkbox is unchecked. For example when I uncheck first checkbox, I will got in `selected` items of second checkbox instead of array. (selected will `[{id: 5, ...}, {id: 8, ...}]` )

I need that because I need check or uncheck whole group of checkboxes.

Is possible do that in Vue? I didn't find anything about it in docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a computed property that takes selected and returns the flattened array, so for example have the computed property flatSelected:

```
export default {
    ...,
    computed: {
        flatSelected () {
            return this.selected.reduce((acc, cur) => [ ...acc, ...cur ], [])
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your template have the following

```
<template>
   <input v-for="item in itemsGroup" type="checkbox" :value="item" v-model="selected">
   <input v-for="item in flatSelected" type="checkbox" :value="item" v-model="flatSelected">
</template>
```

Comment: I was just about to paste this exact answer from my text editor. =(

Comment: @gillyhl thanks for answer, but where to use this property?

Comment: Check my updated answer, if you export your Vue component like that, it'll be like the answer, add a property called computed in the export, and define the computed property you want. See the docs for a better explaination https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: @gillyhl Thanks but I know how to use computed properties, but I don't know where to use this flatSelected. I need hold updated selected field because I also have checkboxes which has values as single object not array of objects

Comment: Updated answer, I think this is what you need.

Comment: @gillyhl Thanks for your effort to help me. Maybe I just write bad question. I edit my code to show you why I need modify selected by adding or removing items and not array of items. I hope it better for understand :/ Btw. sorry for my English.

Comment: I would suggest either using @change events on your inputs to append or remove the selected items into a flattened array. Or refactor your groups to an array of objects that stores what has been selected and query that